# Python 3 AWS lambda function to get users access key age

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, boto3

I'm trying to get the access key age for each user in multiple AWS accounts. I currently have code that prints out the access key age but the code doesn't return it properly from an error. The code I'm working with is,

```
import boto3
from time import gmtime, strftime
from datetime import datetime
sts = boto3.client('sts')

def lambda_handler(event, context):
    rolesessionname = "rolename"
    account = "123456789"
    response = sts.assume_role(
    RoleArn = "arn:aws:iam::" + str(account) + ":role/audit",
    RoleSessionName= rolesessionname
    )
  credentials = response['Credentials']
  iam = boto3.client(
   'iam',
    aws_access_key_id = credentials['AccessKeyId'], 
    aws_secret_access_key = credentials['SecretAccessKey'], 
    aws_session_token = credentials['SessionToken']
    )


    response = iam.list_users()
    nameList = []
    todaysDate = strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S", gmtime())
    todaysDate = str(todaysDate)
    todaysDate = todaysDate[0:10]
    todaysDate = datetime.strptime(todaysDate, "%Y-%m-%d")

    for person in response["Users"]:
        curPersonName = person["UserName"]

        keys = iam.list_access_keys(UserName=curPersonName)
        for keyData in keys["AccessKeyMetadata"]:
           keyID = keyData["AccessKeyId"]
           status = keyData["Status"]
            CreateDate = keyData.get("CreateDate","none")
            CreateDate = str(CreateDate)
            CreateDate = CreateDate[0:10]
            CreateDate = datetime.strptime(CreateDate, "%Y-%m-%d")

            totalDays =  abs((CreateDate - todaysDate).days)
            print (totalDays-1)
            nameList.append({
            "UserName:":curPersonName,
            "Status:": status,
            "Create Date": CreateDate
            #"Total days:" : totalDays-1
                })            

     return nameList
```

My problem is that if I comment out the mentions of

`CreateDate = datetime.strptime(CreateDate, "%Y-%m-%d")`

and

`totalDays =  abs((CreateDate - todaysDate).days)`

I get successful build and return data, just without the age of the key which is mainly what I want. However if I keep those lines in and print out to see if it's getting the age correctly it is. However It only prints them out and then errors with.

```
{
  "errorMessage": "datetime.datetime(2017, 1, 11, 0, 0) is not JSON serializable",
  "errorType": "TypeError",
  "stackTrace": [
    [
      "/var/lang/lib/python3.6/json/__init__.py",
      238,
      "dumps",
      "**kw).encode(obj)"
    ],
    [
      "/var/lang/lib/python3.6/json/encoder.py",
      199,
      "encode",
      "chunks = self.iterencode(o, _one_shot=True)"
    ],
    [
      "/var/lang/lib/python3.6/json/encoder.py",
      257,
      "iterencode",
      "return _iterencode(o, 0)"
    ],
    [
      "/var/runtime/awslambda/bootstrap.py",
      110,
      "decimal_serializer",
      "raise TypeError(repr(o) + \" is not JSON serializable\")"
    ]
  ]
}
```

Comment: Have you tried using `strftime` instead of `strptime`?

Comment: I just tried changing them. But I'm getting unsupported type errors when trying to subtract the two data values. Are you saying to not strip the create date string down as well in order to use strftime?

Comment: Are you ever required to print `CreateDate` and `todaysDate`?

Comment: No I am not required to

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're getting this error because `datetime` is not JSON serializable. You are saving a `datetime` object in `CreateDate` with

```
datetime.strptime(CreateDate, "%Y-%m-%d")
```

It seems like the answer would be to use this value to calculate your days:

```
totalDays =  abs((CreateDate - todaysDate).days)
```

and then change it to a string representation before adding it to the return object:

```
CreateDate = CreateDate.isoformat() #or whatever return format you want.
```

Comment: That did in fact fix the problem! Thanks a ton for the help!